# Is there is a way to manually add web credentials in windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, registry, credential-manager

Is there is a way to manually add web credentials in windows 10? I have been searching for some time and the only way that I found was by using vaultcmd which does not work on windows 10.

Any ideas regarding how to manually add web credentials in windows 10 using PowerSell or registry or other means? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get VaultCmd to work in Windows 10:

```
VaultCmd /addcreds:"Web Credentials" /credtype:"Windows Web Password Credential" /identity:"username on website" /authenticator:"password on website" /resource:"https://WebSiteURL"
```

Note that the parameters to `/addcreds:` and `/credtype:` are case sensitive.

Comment: thank u for sharing this... I am not so IT guy here, but i have a question... i can add the website credentials to web credentials manager with no problem using this command, but I am trying to have it for http site (not https) and it is not working... it wont work for http websites?! is there other way around?

Comment: I don't know about that directly, but it would not surprise me at all if Microsoft didn't want you saving credentials that would log into websites unencrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Running the command from @WaitingForGuacamole resulted in an error: `Invalid schema: Element not found.`

The below command worked, I got this example by running `VaultCmd /addcreds /?`

```
vaultcmd /addcreds:"Web Credentials" /credtype:{3CCD5499-87A8-4B10-A215-608888DD3B55} /identity:TestCred /authenticator:Test /resource:server /savedBy:Test
```